# RDP into EC2 not able to use GPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu, rdp

My teammate is running into an issue where 3D rendering is extremely slow. Running the same 3D desktop program on an older laptop is faster than the EC2 instance. He has tried upping the EC2 type to use GPU types.

He hypothesizes that when using RDP into the machine, the EC2 is not able to connect to the GPU. He thinks that the GPU types are geared for machine learning tasks running entirely locally on the machine instead of running 3D desktop programs that needs to feed to a RDP client. He has seen Azure VMs properly using GPU rendering but AWS has other services for running 3D desktop programs remotely that is not available for us to use.

Sorry if I'm not making a lot of sense because I'm paraphrasing his experience.

Has anyone encountered something like this?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I believe this is one problem using [NICE DCV](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/dcv/) instead of RDP is meant to solve

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for the info and link. I asked him about it and he says he tried NICE DCV but it was not available on the GovCloud region because the GovCloud region doesn't have the appropriate license as the other commercial regions. Do you happen to know of an alternative solution or a workaround for the GovCloud region? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of solution.  As I understand it, if you manually install the NICE DCV server and it can't get a license it'll operate in a demo license mode for 15 days, though I have no experience with manual installation, or alternative license modes.

Comment: @AnonCoward thank you for detailing that licensing issue. Can you please write up your comments as an answer? I'll mark it as the accepted answer unless someone else offers another solution. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: Sure, hope someone else can come up with a better solution for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you look into using [NICE DCV](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/dcv/).  It's designed to cover scenarios where you want to run GPU intensive tasks, both Graphical and otherwise, in the cloud and view the results locally.  Specifically from the introduction page:

> **3D Graphics Visualization**
>
> HPC workloads across industry verticals such as Oil & Gas, Life Sciences, and Design & Engineering are getting increasingly complex and consume massive amounts of data. NICE DCV's streaming protocol eliminates the need to ship output files to client devices and provides a smooth and bandwidth-efficient experience to stream HPC 3D graphics remotely.

Be aware, it's not completely free software:

> **Amazon EC2:**
>
> There is no additional cost for using NICE DCV on AWS. Customers pay only for the EC2 resources that they use.
>
> **Third Party Cloud and On-Premises:**
>
> For more details on NICE DCV licensing, resellers, and pricing, please contact  nice-sales@amazon.com

Most people will use it in one of the AWS supported regions, so there is no cost beyond the costs with running the EC2 instance itself.  It just needs to be able to talk to some components in AWS to verify it's properly licensed.  If you're running it somewhere else, like on-premises, or in the GovCloud regions, you'll need to work with NICE and/or AWS directly to procure a license.

If you consider going that route, I'd highly recommend testing it out either in a region where it is supported, or use the 15 day free trial to verify it'll work for your scenarios.